# Errno 14 HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required Yum

Tags: redhat, yum

I am having an issue with my own *yum repo*; I have basic auth on Apache running on a RHEL 6.2 machine on EC2.

It holds the yum repo for both a RHEL 6 machine and a RHEL 5 machine in which I have the RPM's in a separate folder within.

When I do my `yum update` on any RHEL 6 machine, it's fine, everything works, but when I run it on a RHEL 5.5 machine, I get the error below;

> [Errno 14] HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required.

I know for a fact that I can access the machine and the username and password is correct as I can copy and paste what is in the repo file and it works in a web browser no problem.

I suspect there is an issue with a RHEL6x machine serving up a repo for a 5.x machine but can't find the solution.

What could be the problem and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

Double check that the repositories configured are indeed the ones that you are expecting to see. You can run `yum repolist -v | grep baseurl` to see all URLs that yum would try to download. You could then use `wget` to download each of them and see if you get a similar error. Maybe even append `/repodata/repomd.xml` to the end of each URL which is what yum would do first anyway.